# When using SharePoint 2010 rest api - /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList, what is difference between Name and Account

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

In SharePoint when I call the `listdata.svc/UserInformationList`, can someone help me understand Account versus Name?

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
    <d:ContentTypeID>0x010A00F8C6531A37316E499095FDC0720C4D90</d:ContentTypeID>
    <d:ContentType>Person</d:ContentType>
    <d:Name>TESTDOMAIN\administrator</d:Name>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-04-30T16:50:53</d:Modified>
    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-04-30T16:50:53</d:Created>
    <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1073741823</d:CreatedById>
    <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1073741823</d:ModifiedById>
    <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
    <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
    <d:Path>/_catalogs/users</d:Path>
    <d:Account>i:0#.w|TESTDOMAIN\administrator</d:Account>
    <d:EMail m:null="true" />
    <d:MobileNumber m:null="true" />
    <d:AboutMe m:null="true" />
    <d:SIPAddress m:null="true" />
    <d:IsSiteAdmin m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsSiteAdmin>
    <d:Deleted m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Deleted>
    <d:Hidden m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Hidden>
    <d:Picture m:null="true" />
    <d:Department m:null="true" />
    <d:JobTitle m:null="true" />
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

What is the difference between the two?

In the account xml `<d:Account>i:0#.w|TESTDOMAIN\administrator</d:Account>` what does the `i:0#.w` mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prefix **i:0#.w|** before the username is to identify the type of authentication.

```
i : for an identity claim, otherwise it will be 'c'

# : for user logon name otherwise it will be $ : email address otherwise it will be % : Farm ID

w : for windows authentication OR f : form based authentication.
```

For details please take a look in below images,

**Image 1 :**

[image]

**Image 2 :**

[image]

[Source](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Name` is for *Display Name* actually, so if you sync your user details from a directory, the `<d:Name>TESTDOMAIN\administrator</d:Name>` is likely to be replaced by `<d:Name>Actual Full Name</d:Name>`, while `Account` will remain unchanged.